# How to install auto-sklearn on GoogleColab?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

I'd like to use [auto-sklearn](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/).I used the code from this [document](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/).All packages are installed. But I got an error like this.

```
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install 
!pip install auto-sklearn
import autosklearn.classification


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f7b2b884019b> in <module>()
     24 from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
     25 from keras.metrics import categorical_accuracy
---> 26 import autosklearn.classification
     27 
     28 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/autosklearn/classification.py in <module>()
----> 1 from autosklearn.estimators import AutoSklearnClassifier

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/autosklearn/estimators.py in <module>()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 
----> 5 from autosklearn.automl import AutoMLClassifier, AutoMLRegressor
      6 from autosklearn.util.backend import create

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/base.py in <module>()
     12 from ..base import BaseEstimator
     13 from ..base import MetaEstimatorMixin
---> 14 from ..utils import _get_n_jobs, check_random_state
     15 from ..externals import six
     16 from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

ImportError: cannot import name '_get_n_jobs'
```

I tried [this advice](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11656) which is about specify install folder.But I have still same error...

Can somebody give me a hand?

### add

I tried tidylobster and CrepeGoat solutions.Then I got another error message which is like below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in _dep_map(self)
   2896         try:
-> 2897             return self.__dep_map
   2898         except AttributeError:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
   2690         if attr.startswith('_'):
-> 2691             raise AttributeError(attr)
   2692         return getattr(self._provider, attr)

AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in _parsed_pkg_info(self)
   2887         try:
-> 2888             return self._pkg_info
   2889         except AttributeError:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
   2690         if attr.startswith('_'):
-> 2691             raise AttributeError(attr)
   2692         return getattr(self._provider, attr)

AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e20ebb276309> in <module>()
      5 get_ipython().system('pip install auto-sklearn')
      6 
----> 7 import autosklearn.classification

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/autosklearn/__init__.py in <module>()
     16 '''
     17 
---> 18 dependencies.verify_packages(__MANDATORY_PACKAGES__)
     19 
     20 if os.name != 'posix':

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/autosklearn/util/dependencies.py in verify_packages(packages)
     25             operation = match.group('operation1')
     26             version = match.group('version1')
---> 27             _verify_package(name, operation, version)
     28         else:
     29             raise ValueError('Unable to read requirement: %s' % package)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/autosklearn/util/dependencies.py in _verify_package(name, operation, version)
     32 def _verify_package(name, operation, version):
     33     try:
---> 34         module = pkg_resources.get_distribution(name)
     35         installed_version = LooseVersion(module.version)
     36     except pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in get_distribution(dist)
    477         dist = Requirement.parse(dist)
    478     if isinstance(dist, Requirement):
--> 479         dist = get_provider(dist)
    480     if not isinstance(dist, Distribution):
    481         raise TypeError("Expected string, Requirement, or Distribution", dist)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in get_provider(moduleOrReq)
    353     """Return an IResourceProvider for the named module or requirement"""
    354     if isinstance(moduleOrReq, Requirement):
--> 355         return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
    356     try:
    357         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in require(self, *requirements)
    896         included, even if they were already activated in this working set.
    897         """
--> 898         needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
    899 
    900         for dist in needed:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    790 
    791             # push the new requirements onto the stack
--> 792             new_requirements = dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1]
    793             requirements.extend(new_requirements)
    794 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in requires(self, extras)
   2633     def requires(self, extras=()):
   2634         """List of Requirements needed for this distro if `extras` are used"""
-> 2635         dm = self._dep_map
   2636         deps = []
   2637         deps.extend(dm.get(None, ()))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in _dep_map(self)
   2897             return self.__dep_map
   2898         except AttributeError:
-> 2899             self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
   2900             return self.__dep_map
   2901 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in _compute_dependencies(self)
   2906         reqs = []
   2907         # Including any condition expressions
-> 2908         for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
   2909             reqs.extend(parse_requirements(req))
   2910 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in _parsed_pkg_info(self)
   2888             return self._pkg_info
   2889         except AttributeError:
-> 2890             metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
   2891             self._pkg_info = email.parser.Parser().parsestr(metadata)
   2892             return self._pkg_info

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in get_metadata(self, name)
   1408         if not self.egg_info:
   1409             return ""
-> 1410         value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
   1411         return value.decode('utf-8') if six.PY3 else value
   1412 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in _get(self, path)
   1520 
   1521     def _get(self, path):
-> 1522         with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
   1523             return stream.read()
   1524 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.20.1.dist-info/METADATA'
```

I searched [not found scikit_learn-0.20.1.dist-info/METADATA](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=2nD&channel=fs&ei=I-cZXKD0C4qs8QWfzZ2QAQ&q=scikit_learn-0.20.1.dist-info%2FMETADATA&oq=scikit_learn-0.20.1.dist-info%2FMETADATA&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12526.13043..13340...0.0..0.393.393.3-1......0....1..gws-wiz.8qdKp-z0Duc) .But I haven't find good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `sudo apt-get` to install swig as in 
[the AutoScikitLearn instructions for Ubuntu](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/installation.html#ubuntu-installation)<s>,
and do a `!sudo apt-get upgrade` to get the most recent versions of everything. In full:</s>

```
!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt-get install build-essential swig
!sudo apt-get upgrade
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
!pip install auto-sklearn

import autosklearn.classification
```

So I reran my code, and the errors I'm getting are ***very*** strange. Because I get the same errors as @Nori described, but **they disappear on the third attempt to import**. Knowing that, it's easy to write a dirty hack to get around it:

```
!sudo apt-get install build-essential swig
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
!pip install auto-sklearn

for _ in range(3):
    try:
        import autosklearn.classification
        break
    except:
        pass
else:
    raise ImportError("failed to import from autosklearn")
```

But unfortunately, I have **zero** idea why this is the case.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I update apt and install swig.But I got another error. I add the error message on this post. do you have any idea?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now auto ml is work on my Google Colab!

Answer (score 3):

Have you also installed building packages? I've just tried following steps and it worked out properly.

```
!sudo apt-get install build-essential swig
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
!pip install auto-sklearn
import autosklearn.classification
```

There're some packages being compiled during the dependency installation. So if you don't have build-essentials installed before `!curl ...`, this can be the cause.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I overlooked that on ubuntu install. I tried your answer.But I got another error. I add the error message on this post. do you have any idea?

Comment: Yeah, it kinda strange. I've also met it, but when I dug into it to see which Python version am I using. `import sys; sys.executable` was `/usr/bin/python3` (or similiar), but not the same as in the error message. Then I re-imported `autosklearn` and the error message disappeared. I don't have any explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: I see... It has some problem.CrepeGoat solution solved the problem! Thank you for your support :-)