# cant install auto-sklearn in my jupyter notebook

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook in Windows. I have tried many commands including the ones below from different pages, none could solve and i get errors. Has anyone found a workaround? even if i can install it in Google Colab would be fine.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip3 install
pip3 install auto-sklearn
```

or

```
sudo pip install autosklearn
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Linux... see system requirements here: https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/installation.html

`pip install auto-sklearn`

worked for me using Linux. Then

`import autosklearn`.

Answer (score 0):

Autosklearn version 0.10.0 works fine on google colab

```
!pip install auto-sklearn==0.10.0
```

You might need additional commands [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53840687/10704399)

Colab might ask you to restart itself , after which the autosklearn import would work