# Unable to run autosklearn on colab

Tags: scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run auto-sklearn on Google colab. I have successfully installed AutoSklearn but it gives me error while running following code:

Input:

```
import autosklearn.classfication
```

Output:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IncorrectPackageVersionError              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-bb85952a9dd8> in <module>()
----> 1 import autosklearn.classification

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/autosklearn/util/dependencies.py in _verify_package(name, operation, version)
     60     if not check:
     61         raise IncorrectPackageVersionError(name, installed_version, operation,
---> 62                                            required_version)
     63 
     64 

IncorrectPackageVersionError: found 'distributed' version 1.25.3 but requires distributed version >=2.2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the issue with the current version of auto sklearn , if you are ok with a older version then 0.10.0 works perfectly with colab

```
!pip install auto-sklearn==0.10.0
```

You might need additional commands
[as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53840687/10704399)

Reiterating the commands here for version 0.10.0

```
!sudo apt-get install build-essential swig 
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install 
!pip install auto-sklearn==0.10.0
```

Colab might ask you to restart itself , after which the autosklearn import would work

Comment: @Y LEE thank you for the answer. I will try and update the outcome here. However, yes, you are right it is a version error, I installed older version 0.6.0 and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: You can use the latest version the important part are the three commands and the restarting even if Colab does not demand it.See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65398572/2529666