# Error in Colab when trying to import autosklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to work with Autosklearn in Google Colab, for which I have done the following steps:

```
!apt-get install build-essential swig 
!pip install auto-sklearn
```

I get the following error when I try to

```
import autosklearn

IncorrectPackageVersionError: found 'scikit-learn' version 0.22.2.post1 but requires scikit-learn version >=0.23.0
```

I have tried to do the following:

```
!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn

Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy>=0.19.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.19.4)
```

```
!pip install -U scikit-learn

Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy>=0.19.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.0.0)
```

```
!pip install scikit-learn==0.23.2

Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn==0.23.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn==0.23.2) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn==0.23.2) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn==0.23.2) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn==0.23.2) (2.1.0)
```

but when I check the sklearn version I see the following:

```
import sklearn

print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))

The scikit-learn version is 0.22.2.post1.
```

And I still get the error when I try to import autosklearn

How else can I install /upgrade to scikit-learn version 0.23.2 (current version)?

Comment: maybe you have to use `Python 3.7` or `Python 3.8` instead of `Python 3.6`?

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that Colab imports scikit-learn already at startup (version 0.22.2.post1), before you manually install the new version (version 0.23.2). If you restart your runtime after the install, the new version will be used.

Comment: probably need to import sklearn before importing autosklearn

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for in the last 2weeks.
I want to use Pycaret which requires sklearn 0.23.2 but google colab auto imports its own version of sklearn.
restarting the runtime and installing your desired version will solve the problem will enable you use your version.